# CSS text real see through

Tags: html, css, transparency, transparent

Ok, I'm trying to do something like that.

Let's say I have a `BODY` with a background image. On this body, I have a `position:fixed` full screen `DIV#a` with a gradient background and `mix-blend-mode: exclusion`.

Now, I want to add another `DIV#b` with a black background and some text. But I want my text to be "transparent" so we can see the colors of the `DIV#b` through the text.

Is that possible using only CSS (I don't want to use svg or anything else, only text and css).
Does the text has to be directly in DIV#b or can I put it in another div inside the DIV#b ?

The CSS gradient I have is animated using css, so I need the text to react with it, I can't cheat.

The html result would be

```
<body>
    <div id="a"></div> <!-- position:fixed, animated gradient and mix-blend-mode: exclusion -->
    <div id="b"> <!-- dark background div -->
        <span>some text</span> <!-- "transparent text" that is colored with #a -->
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: could you share your css code as well?

Comment: Or maybe an image of what this ought to look like? It's worded a little confusingly

Comment: Thanks for your answer @demkovych and tylerH . My post has been marked as duplicate. I can see that maybe it's possible. Thanks